# BLOb: cannot read all data,but few kb

Tags: java, mysql, database, file, blob

I am using BLOb support for inserting and reading from MySQl.(JDBC)
I can do that,but when it reads,its only few kb's.I dont know why.
here is the working code:

```
 import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class InsertAndRetrieveImage {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  int id=7;
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/newdb";;
Connection con=null;
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "sesame");

 PreparedStatement ps = null;

 ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT IGNORE INTO image VALUES(?,?,?)");

         File file = new File("e:/anarkali.wav");


         FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);

     try{
        System.out.println(fs.available());
         ps.setInt(1,id);
         ps.setBinaryStream(2,fs,fs.available());
         String filen=file.getName();
      ps.setString(3,filen);


      int i = ps.executeUpdate();



        String filename="filename";OutputStream os=null;byte[] content=null;
        ps= con.prepareStatement("SELECT fs from image where id=7");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
         System.out.println(rs);
      while(rs.next()) {


            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("fs");

        content = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());


        os = new FileOutputStream(new File("e://testanar.wav"));

    }
    os.write(content);
    os.close();
    con.close();
    ps.close();}
     catch(SQLException e)
     {System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }

  }catch(Exception ex){}


  }
```

Is the problem while reading or writing?my BLOb's size is somewhat `65535`.Is this is the bug?

Comment: What is the actual value of `blob.length()` (just after `Blob blob = rs.getBlob("fs");`) ?

Comment: @YaK it's not displaying blob.length().Its throwing exception null.whats the problem??i know its size and stuff,but what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is correct. If the file size is small then it will work fine. If you are using `BLOB` datatype to store that binary data,change it to `LONGBLOB`. Because if you tried to save a file in `BLOB` data field, and if the file size is more than max allowed size of BLOB datatype then the content will be truncated and you will loss some content of file(depends on file size). Even if you use `LONGBLOB` datatype there are some things you must check. I'll explain

In mysql website we can see that max file size of `LONGBLOB` is 4GB. But it depends on many things. To store large file you have to check some things. First thing is in `my.ini` file, there is a property called `max_allowed_packet`, it specifies largest possible packet that can be transmitted to or from a mysql client or server. You should set `max_allowed_packet` property to a higher value. And restart mysql. Some file system won't allow 4GB files. In that case you cant load that much big file.

I think in your case setting `max_allowed_packet` property to a higher value will fix the problem.

I think you can use following table creation script

```
CREATE TABLE `image` (
    `id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fs` LONGBLOB NULL,
    `filen` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: @joeyrohan- Restarted mysql after modifying that value?

Comment: @joeyrohan- Also tell me what is the file size of 'e:/anarkali.wav'?

Comment: yup..i tried this around 1 month back 10 times.No result.
anarkali.wav is about 4 mb.

Answer (score 1):

As you know every parameter have fix value length, here is the example.

```
    0 < length <=      255  -->  `TINYBLOB`
     255 < length <=    65535  -->  `BLOB`
   65535 < length <= 16777215  -->  `MEDIUMBLOB`
16777215 < length <=    2³¹-1  -->  `LONGBLOB`


TINYBLOB: maximum length of 255 bytes
BLOB: maximum length of 65,535 bytes
MEDIUMBLOB: maximum length of 16,777,215 bytes
LONGBLOB: maximum length of 4,294,967,295 bytes
```

this MAX size is not bug,but its length to store value

In your case Use `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB`.

Comment: well i am using MySql,and there is only one type:BLOb.
And it is kind of medium blob.But i am sure problem is not about the size of BLOb but,the execution.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem a few days ago and what i did is not to use the InputStream available method.

use:

```
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fs);
```

but you have to verify because there are some jdbc drivers that not support it